# What's the relationship between output of qubit measurements and classification of data in Quantum Machine Learning?

Tags: q#, machine-learning

I'm training a model in Q# which has more than 2 features. 
I have trouble understanding the following things:

- How is the data classified based on the qubit states?

For example: If I have only 2 features (and want to classify our input as class A and class B) then only a single qubit would be used.
 After measuring if the qubit turns out to be in the 0 state then its class A and in case of 1 its class B (or vice-versa).

But now if I have say 4 features then 2 qubits would be used and i could have 4 possible outcomes:

$$
|00\rangle,\quad  |01\rangle,\quad  |10\rangle,\quad  |11\rangle.
$$

So how would the data be classified based on these states?

- Also am I correct in thinking that all the qubits are measured or is only 1 qubit measured and classified as class A/B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one qubit is measured; the frequency of getting 0/1 result in this measurement (rather than a single measurement result) is used together with the bias to assign the class.

If you dig into the source code of the QML library, the measurement is performed in [EstimateClassificationProbability](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/bb75af3caa54b99b6e68989fe9fb1de0cc6d0b65/MachineLearning/src/Classification.qs#L40) operation, which measures the last qubit of the register.